# ARD and dockutil?

Tags: macos, dock, remote-desktop, unix

This is probably a pretty noobish question, but here goes...

I've recently discovered Kyle Crawford's [dockutil](http://github.com/kcrawford/dockutil), but I can't make it work with Apple Remote Desktop. Or rather: I can't make it work with ARD's "Send UNIX Command" feature. It works fine on single machines (i.e. working in Terminal on a remote Mac controlled via ARD), but sending dockutil commands to multiple Macs (with dockutil installed on them) fails.

Why? And is there a solution?

If anyone can shed any light on this I'd be really grateful.

TIA.

Comment: To start, exactly what command are you sending and what error are you getting back

Comment: Hi Tony, and thanks for answering :) Sending any "dockutil" commands (e.g. dockutil --add /Applications/Whatever.app --allhomes) using "Send UNIX Command" produces a command-not-recognised error. But inputing the same command into Terminal on a remote computer controlled via ARD works fine.

Comment: Could you put an exact example and the exact return, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the complete path to your command? The "Send UNIX command" doesn't use the same PATH as you. If memory serves it uses the same one as the root login but it may be even shorter than that.

I always put the complete path regardless.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I'll check it out and report back (dot dot dot). Thanks again.

Comment: ...and you're absolutely right :) If you preface the command with /usr/local/bin/ it works. Thank you for your help!